# Mysql check if record doesnt exits add it

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I want add to wp_postmeta meta_key record if this doesn't exists.

I had this query, but from something strange reason it doesn't work anymore. Please help!

```
 INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (meta_key, meta_value, post_id)
SELECT '_update_date', '', ID FROM wp_posts WHERE wp_posts.post_type='product'
AND NOT EXISTS  (SELECT meta_key FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_update_date' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you wanted to insert into `wp_postmeta` IF
>
> > `SELECT '_update_date', '', ID FROM wp_posts WHERE wp_posts.post_type='product'`
>
> Doesn't EXISTS.....

I think this query will work . You were confused with syntax and missed `where`

```
  `INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (meta_key, meta_value, post_id) 
        SELECT meta_key FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_update_date'
        WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT '_update_date', '', ID FROM wp_posts WHERE
        wp_posts.post_type='product')`
```

Hope this helps.